# as far as this from success was Dawe

Tags: meaning-in-context

**As far as this from success was Dawe** when he grasped editor'sleeve... can anyone tell me with the other words the meaning of the phrase? thank you!

Comment: Hello, Nana. ELL, our sister site, is perhaps where basic questions like this should be asked, though the 'sentence' is very poor. I'd expect  'Dave was **_this_** [holding finger and thumb 1cm apart] far from success when he grasped the editor's sleeve.' But I couldn't be sure.

Comment: Could you check that you have typed the sentence perfectly.  Please could you tell us where you read or heard it. Do you have a link to the original text? If so please give that as well

Answer (score 1):

I have found the full text at https://archive.org/stream/completeworksofo002824mbp/completeworksofo002824mbp_djvu.txt

> "It's Maupassant hash," said Mrs. Dawe. "It may not be art, but I
> do wish you would do a five-course Marion Crawford serial with an Ella
> Wheeler Wilcox sonnet for dessert. I'm hungry."

> As far as this from success was Shackleford Dawe when he plucked
> Editor Westbrook's sleeve in Madison Square. That was the first time
> the editor had seen Dawe in several months.

> "Why, Shack, is this you?" said Westbrook, somewhat awkwardly, for
> the form of his phrase seemed to touch upon the other's changed ap-
> pearance.

I understand the expression to be saying that the distance between Shackleford Dawe and success (whatever he wanted to achieve) when he grasped editor's sleeve is being compared to some other distant prospect.

It's possibly the distance beween the hash that Mrs Dawe refers to and the fancy five part composition she compares it with.

It's a complicated way of saying something like this.

> His house was several miles from the city centre and his chances of winning Mary's heart were just about as distant.

The writing is not easy to follow, even for native English speakers.